# Interesting tree/hierarchical data structure problem

Tags: sql, database, tree, normalization, hierarchy

Colleges have different ways of organizing their departments.  Some schools go `School -> Term -> Department`.  Others have steps in between, with the longest being `School -> Sub_Campus -> Program -> Term -> Division -> Department`.

`School`, `Term`, and `Department` are the only ones that always exist in a school's "tree" of departments.  The order of these categories never changes, with the second example I gave you being the longest.  Every step down is a 1:N relationship.

Now, I'm not sure how to set up the relationships between the tables.  For example, what columns are in `Term`?  Its parent could be a `Program`, `Sub_Campus`, or `School`.  Which one it is depends on the school's system.  I could conceive of setting up the `Term` table to have foreign keys for all of those (which all would default to `NULL`), but I'm not sure this is the canonical way of doing things here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking -- do you want a solution to the problem of fitting multiple different hierarchical data models in to the same database implementation?  Or a solution that shows how to imiplement a single hierarchical model?

Comment: Either one, whichever would better fit this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you better use a general table, called e.g. Entity which would contain *id* field and a self-referencing *parent* field.

Each relevant table would contain a field pointing to Entity's id (1:1). In a way each table would be a child of the Entity table.

Comment: a _parent_ field is ok, but it requires database-specific support to do a heirarchical query (e.g., Oracle's `connect by prior` construct).  An alternate approach which makes querying much easier is representing the heirarchy in a single encoded column where a subtree is defined as a string prefix of that column.

Comment: yeah, but that was not the question, and adding this is not such a big deal. I wrote about this recently for this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181489/problem-with-hierarchical-database-model/7181872#7181872

Comment: @evil otto: wrong. The database _model_ can be recursive, but the _query_ that pulls the data from the database tables could simply iterate "until no more parent records found". That is the way that most client apps would do it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one design possibility:

This option takes advantage of your special constraints. Basically you generalize all hierarchies as that of the longest form by introducing generic nodes. If school doesn't have "sub campus" then just assign it a generic sub campus called "Main". For example, `School -> Term -> Department` can be thought of same as `School -> Sub_Campus = Main -> Program=Main -> Term -> Division=Main -> Department`. In this case, we assign a node called "Main" as default when school doesn't have that nodes. Now you can just have a boolean flag property for these generic nodes that indicates that they are just placeholders and this flag would allow you to filter it out in middle layer or in UX if needed.

This design will allow you to take advantage of all relational constraints as usual and simplify handling of missing node types in your code.

Answer (score 3):

```
-- Enforcing a taxonomy by self-referential (recursive) tables.
-- Both the classes and the instances have a recursive structure.
-- The taxonomy is enforced mostly based on constraints on the classes,
-- the instances only need to check that {their_class , parents_class} 
-- form a valid pair.
--
DROP schema school CASCADE;
CREATE schema school;

CREATE TABLE school.category
  ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , category_name VARCHAR
  );
INSERT INTO school.category(id, category_name) VALUES
  ( 1, 'School' )
  , ( 2, 'Sub_campus' )
  , ( 3, 'Program' )
  , ( 4, 'Term' )
  , ( 5, 'Division' )
  , ( 6, 'Department' )
  ;

-- This table contains a list of all allowable {child->parent} pairs.
-- As a convention, the "roots" of the trees point to themselves.
-- (this also avoids a NULL FK)
CREATE TABLE school.category_valid_parent
  ( category_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES school.category (id)
  , parent_category_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES school.category (id)
  );
ALTER TABLE school.category_valid_parent
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (category_id, parent_category_id)
  ;

INSERT INTO school.category_valid_parent(category_id, parent_category_id)
  VALUES
  ( 1,1) -- school -> school
  , (2,1) -- subcampus -> school
  , (3,1) -- program -> school
  , (3,2) -- program -> subcampus
  , (4,1) -- term -> school
  , (4,2) -- term -> subcampus
  , (4,3) -- term -> program
  , (5,4) -- division --> term
  , (6,4) -- department --> term
  , (6,5) -- department --> division
  ;

CREATE TABLE school.instance
  ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , category_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES school.category (id)
  , parent_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES school.instance (id)
  -- NOTE: parent_category_id is logically redundant
  -- , but needed to maintain the constraint
  -- (without referencing a third table)
  , parent_category_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES school.category (id)
  , instance_name VARCHAR
  );      -- Forbid illegal combinations of {parent_id, parent_category_id}
ALTER TABLE school.instance ADD CONSTRAINT valid_cat UNIQUE (id,category_id);
ALTER TABLE school.instance
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (parent_id, parent_category_id)
      REFERENCES school.instance(id, category_id);
  ;
  -- Forbid illegal combinations of {category_id, parent_category_id}
ALTER TABLE school.instance
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (category_id, parent_category_id) 
      REFERENCES school.category_valid_parent(category_id, parent_category_id);
  ;

INSERT INTO school.instance(id, category_id
    , parent_id, parent_category_id
    , instance_name) VALUES
  -- Zulo
  (1,1,1,1, 'University of Utrecht' )
  , (2,2,1,1, 'Uithof' )
  , (3,3,2,2, 'Life sciences' )
  , (4,4,3,3, 'Bacherlor' )
  , (5,5,4,4, 'Biology' )
  , (6,6,5,5, 'Evolutionary Biology' )
  , (7,6,5,5, 'Botany' )
  -- Nulo
  , (11,1,11,1, 'Hogeschool Utrecht' )
  , (12,4,11,1, 'Journalistiek' )
  , (13,6,12,4, 'Begrijpend Lezen' )
  , (14,6,12,4, 'Typvaardigheid' )
  ;

  -- try to insert an invalid instance
INSERT INTO school.instance(id, category_id
    , parent_id, parent_category_id
    , instance_name) VALUES
  ( 15, 6, 3,3, 'Procreation' );

WITH RECURSIVE re AS (
  SELECT i0.parent_id AS pa_id
  , i0.parent_category_id AS pa_cat
  , i0.id AS my_id
  , i0.category_id AS my_cat
  FROM school.instance i0
  WHERE i0.parent_id = i0.id
  UNION
  SELECT i1.parent_id AS pa_id
  , i1.parent_category_id AS pa_cat
  , i1.id AS my_id
  , i1.category_id AS my_cat
  FROM school.instance i1
  , re
  WHERE re.my_id = i1.parent_id
  )
SELECT re.*
  , ca.category_name
  , ins.instance_name
  FROM re
  JOIN school.category ca ON (re.my_cat = ca.id)
  JOIN school.instance ins ON (re.my_id = ins.id)
  -- WHERE re.my_id = 14
  ;
```

The output:

```
INSERT 0 11
ERROR:  insert or update on table "instance" violates foreign key constraint "instance_category_id_fkey1"
DETAIL:  Key (category_id, parent_category_id)=(6, 3) is not present in table "category_valid_parent".
 pa_id | pa_cat | my_id | my_cat | category_name |     instance_name 
-------+--------+-------+--------+---------------+-----------------------
     1 |      1 |     1 |      1 | School        | University of Utrecht
    11 |      1 |    11 |      1 | School        | Hogeschool Utrecht
     1 |      1 |     2 |      2 | Sub_campus    | Uithof
    11 |      1 |    12 |      4 | Term          | Journalistiek
     2 |      2 |     3 |      3 | Program       | Life sciences
    12 |      4 |    13 |      6 | Department    | Begrijpend Lezen
    12 |      4 |    14 |      6 | Department    | Typvaardigheid
     3 |      3 |     4 |      4 | Term          | Bacherlor
     4 |      4 |     5 |      5 | Division      | Biology
     5 |      5 |     6 |      6 | Department    | Evolutionary Biology
     5 |      5 |     7 |      6 | Department    | Botany
(11 rows)
```

BTW: I left out the attributes. I propose they could be hooked to the relevant categories by means of a EAV type of data model.

Comment: Note: this is all about "constraint minimisation". In this case, the constraints ensure the topology, even though the topology is represented in a table (and thus: flexible). A change of the allowed topology does not invoke adding or changing a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to start by discussing implementing a single hierarchical model (just 1:N relationships) relationally.

Let's use your example `School -> Term -> Department`.

Here's code that I generated using MySQLWorkbench (I removed a few things to make it clearer):

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`school`  
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- each of these tables would have more attributes in a real implementation
-- using varchar(50)'s for PKs because I can -- :)

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`school` (
  `school_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`school_name`) 
);

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`term`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`term` (
  `term_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `school_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`term_name`, `school_name`) ,
  FOREIGN KEY (`school_name` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`school` (`school_name` )
);

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`department`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`department` (
  `dept_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `term_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `school_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dept_name`, `term_name`, `school_name`) ,
  FOREIGN KEY (`term_name` , `school_name` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`term` (`term_name` , `school_name` )
);
```

Here is the MySQLWorkbench version of the data model:
[image: MySQLWorkbench version]

As you can see, `school`, at the top of the hierarchy, has only `school_name` as its key, whereas `department` has a three-part key including the keys of all of its parents.

**Key points of this solution**

- uses natural keys -- but could be refactored to use surrogate keys ([SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090/surrogate-vs-natural-business-keys) -- along with `UNIQUE` constraints on multi-column foreign keys)
- every level of nesting adds one column to the key
- each table's PK is the entire PK of the table above it, plus an additional column specific to that table

---

Now for the second part of your question.

**My interpretation of the question**
There is a hierarchical data model.  However, some applications require all of the tables, whereas others utilize only some of the tables, skipping the others.  We want to be able to implement *1 single data model* and use it for both of these cases.

You could use the solution given above, and, as ShitalShah mentioned, add a default value to any table which would not be used.    Let's see some example data, using the model given above, where we only want to save `School` and `Department` information (no `Term`s):

```
+-------------+
| school_name |
+-------------+
| hogwarts    |
| uCollege    |
| uMatt       |
+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+-----------+-------------+
| term_name | school_name |
+-----------+-------------+
| default   | hogwarts    |
| default   | uCollege    |
| default   | uMatt       |
+-----------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+-------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| dept_name                     | term_name | school_name |
+-------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| defense against the dark arts | default   | hogwarts    |
| potions                       | default   | hogwarts    |
| basket-weaving                | default   | uCollege    |
| history of magic              | default   | uMatt       |
| science                       | default   | uMatt       |
+-------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Key points**

- there is a default value in `term` for every value in `school` -- this could be quite annoying if you had a table deep in the hierarchy that an application didn't need
- since the table schema doesn't change, the same queries can be used
- queries are easy to write and portable
- SO seems to think `default` should be colored differently

---

There is another solution to storing trees in databases.  Bill Karwin discusses it [here, starting around slide 49](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535062/interesting-tree-hierarchical-data-structure-problem), but I don't think this is the solution you want.  Karwin's solution is for trees of any size, whereas your examples seem to be relatively static.  Also, his solutions come with their own set of problems (but doesn't everything?).

---

I hope that helps with your question.

Comment: Matt, you seem to have left out Sub_Campuses, Programs, and Divisions?

Comment: @babonk  You're right; I wanted to save space and keep the example from getting too long.  Is it too different that it's not clear how it maps to the OP?

Answer (score 1):

For the general problem of fitting hierarchical data in a relational database, the common solutions are adjacency lists (parent-child links like your example) and [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).  As noted in the wikipedia article, Oracle's Tropashko propsed an alternative [nested interval solution](http://www.sigmod.org/publications/sigmod-record/0506/p47-article-tropashko.pdf) but it's still fairly obscure.

The best choice for your situation depends on how you will be querying the structure, and which DB you are using. Cherry picking the article:

> Queries using nested sets can be expected to be faster than queries
>   using a stored procedure to traverse an adjacency list, and so are the
>   faster option for databases which lack native recursive query
>   constructs, such as MySQL

However:

> Nested set are very slow for inserts because it requires updating lft
>   and rgt for all records in the table after the insert. This can cause
>   a lot of database thrash as many rows are rewritten and indexes
>   rebuilt.

Again, depending on how your structure will be queried, you may choose a NoSQL style denormalized `Department` table, with `nullable` foreign keys to all possible parents, avoiding recursive queries altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I would develop this in a very flexible manner and what seems to mean to be the simplest as well:

There should only be one table, lets call it the category_nodes:

```
-- possible content, of this could be stored in another table and create a
-- 1:N -> category:content relationship
drop table if exists category_nodes;
create table category_nodes (
  category_node_id int(11) default null auto_increment,
  parent_id int(11) not null default 1,
  name varchar(256),
  primary key(category_node_id)
);
-- set the first 2 records:
insert into category_nodes (parent_id, name) values( -1, 'root' );
insert into category_nodes (parent_id, name) values( -1, 'uncategorized' );
```

So each record in the table has a unique id, a parent id, and a name.

Now after the first 2 inserts: in category_nodes where the category_node_id is 0 is the root node (the parent of all nodes no matter how many degres away. The second is just for a little helper, set an uncategorized node at the category_node_id = 1 which is also the defalt value of parent_id when inserting into the table.

Now imagining the root categories are School, Term, and Dept you would:

```
insert into category_nodes ( parent_id, name ) values ( 0, 'School' );
insert into category_nodes ( parent_id, name ) values ( 0, 'Term' );
insert into category_nodes ( parent_id, name ) values ( 0, 'Dept' );
```

Then to get all the root categories:

```
select * from category_nodes where parent_id = 0;
```

Now imagining a more complex schema:

```
-- School -> Division -> Department
-- CatX -> CatY
insert into category_nodes ( parent_id, name ) values ( 0, 'School' ); -- imaging gets pkey = 2 
insert into category_nodes ( parent_id, name ) values ( 2, 'Division' ); -- imaging gets pkey = 3
insert into category_nodes ( parent_id, name ) values ( 3, 'Dept' );
--
insert into category_nodes ( parent_id, name ) values ( 0, 'CatX' ); -- 5
insert into category_nodes ( parent_id, name ) values ( 5, 'CatY' );
```

Now to get all the subcategories of School for example:

```
select * from category_nodes where parent_id = 2;
-- or even
select * from category_nodes where parent_id in ( select category_node_id from category_nodes 
    where name = 'School'
);
```

And so on. Thanks to a default = 1 with the parent_id, inserting into the 'uncategorized' category become simple:

```
<?php
$name = 'New cat name';
mysql_query( "insert into category_nodes ( name ) values ( '$name' )" );
```

Cheers